# Getting "Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file" when loading model from transformers

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

When trying load model:

```py
from transformers import TrOCRProcessor,VisionEncoderDecoderModel

model=VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained('microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten')
```

**Getting**:

```
OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for '/home/user/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--microsoft--trocr-base-handwritten/snapshots/69659a277424eb381574e4952f3b3fa3440a419b/pytorch_model.bin' at '/home/user/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--microsoft--trocr-base-handwritten/snapshots/69659a277424eb381574e4952f3b3fa3440a419b/pytorch_model.bin'. If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

Tried downgrading torch with no success, setting from_tf=True and everthing that in here:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4336

Comment: on which platform, environment or IDE are you working?

Comment: linux, venv, intellij

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find the solution all I needed to do is delete the model's folder(`69659a277424eb381574e4952f3b3fa3440a419b` in my case)  from hugging face trocr in:

> /home/user/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--microsoft--trocr-base-handwritten/snapshots/69659a277424eb381574e4952f3b3fa3440a419b

and when I restarted the process the model was downloaded again with no problems.